# How to count the number of scroll events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I'm trying to count the number of scroll which I triggered. I can normally get the number of scrolls, but I want to take the number of times which I have scroll. Say, If i normally scroll for a single time, It contains nearly 4-7 scroll events, where I want to consider that as one. when I scroll a little or a long scroll, i want to take the count of how many times did I have scrolled!

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j4es8d3x/

```
 $(window).on('wheel', function(e){

    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        console.log('scrolling up !');
    }
    else{
        console.log('scrolling down !');
    }
 });
```

Comment: `wheel` event doesn't have `wheelDelta` property, check `deltaY` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) your event:

```
var timer;

$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
     clearTimeout(timer);

     timer = setTimeout(function () {
         // Calculate scrolls here
     }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is well defined pattern for this kind of scenarios. For instance, the **throttle** or **debounce** from lodash:

[image]

- debounce: Grouping a sudden burst of events (like keystrokes) into a single one.
- throttle: Guaranteeing a constant flow of executions every X milliseconds. Like checking every 200ms your scroll position to trigger a CSS animation.

Try below code:

```
_.debounce(yourFunction, 300);
```